# How do I restore python libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I recently downloaded node.js and it installed python version 3.10(I was using 3.9). However, it seems like it deleted python3.9 and it's libraries is there any other way to restore the libraries?
this is the output of pip list (I installed cryptocompare manually)

```
C:\Users\MyName>pip list
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Package            Version
------------------ -----------
certifi            2022.5.18.1
charset-normalizer 2.0.12
cryptocompare      0.7.5
idna               3.3
pip                22.1
pywin32            304
requests           2.27.1
setuptools         58.1.0
urllib3            1.26.9
varint             1.0.2
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
```

Comment: It probably didn't remove the older version, it just added the newer versions path to the PATH and now it's calling the newer version by default

Answer (score 0):

When `pip` uninstalls a package, it first renames it to prefix of `~`, and when it's sure that everything is alright, it will remove the uninstalled package. In your case, it looks like you had problems installing `pip`, the Python packager itself. While I haven't faced this problem myself, most tutorials in the Web suggest that you should remove the offending folders from the distribution folder, that in your case is `c:\python310\lib\site-packages`. That will solve the warning.

If you face further problems with `pip`, if  you should download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and run, that will install a correct `pip` and wheel to a problematic installation.